# ex-style bulk post editing

Tags: bulk

I imported my twitter stream into WP:

http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/category/twitter/

but all the entries now have "barrycarter:" at the beginning.

I realize I could just re-import w/ different settings, but I want a 
more general solution.

Is there a plugin/etc that lets me do "s/barrycarter://isg" on 
selected (or all) posts? In other words, mass-edit, but not by hand.

I realize I could use the API for something like this, but would 
prefer an existing plugin/etc if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

No hands on experience with such, but [*replace* tag of official plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/replace) seems to list some plugins that fit your description.